# std::unordered_map not being updated properly, when modify it in a for loop

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

Trying to update an unordered map using the following code snippet to have only lowercase letters, but it seems to stop after erasing one key-value pair { [33 '!']: 3 } and exits the loop leaving the rest of the map unvisited and prints the partly updated map.

```
 for (auto &i : m)
        if (!(i.first >= 'a' && i.first <= 'z'))
            m.erase(i.first);
```

Following debugging images revealed the above

[image]

[image]

The complete code is herewith:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>    
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line = "Try! Try! Try! until you succeed";
    //getline(cin, line);
    unordered_map<char, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {   
        char lower = (char)tolower(line[i]);
        if (m.find(lower) == m.end())
            m.insert(make_pair(lower, 1));
        else
            m[lower]++;
    }

    for (auto &i : m) //only updates until ! 
        if (!(i.first >= 'a' && i.first <= 'z'))
            m.erase(i.first);

    cout<<"The freq. map so formed is : \n";
    for (auto &i : m)
        cout<<i.first<<"\t"<<i.second<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
/*
OUTPUT : 
The freq. map so formed is : 
d       1
t       4
r       3
e       2
y       4
l       1
o       1
        5
n       1
u       3
i       1
s       1
c       2
*/
```

Can't seem to understand why it won't loop through the complete unordered map.

Also, not sure if this helps towards a clear picture but, when the standard map is used instead of unordered map it gives an Address Boundary Error at the same instance where the next character of the map needs to be updated like so:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Erasing element from container while iterating over it... You cannot used for range for that, you have to fallback to iterator.

Comment: Modifying a container while you iterate over it can lead to problems. I suggest a "normal" `for` loop using iterators, and note what [the `erase` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) *returns*.

Comment: There is an iterator "behind the scenes" in that range loop, and it is invalidated by the `erase`.

Comment: When using a function like `insert` or `erase`, **you must read the documentation** to know what is invalidated (iterator, reference...) for that operation on a given container until you have enough experience to know the rules... Also check what the function returns and samples.

Comment: The "big picture" problem of this question is that the user doesn't see any iterator in the code. In this sense, for-range-based loops give a false sense of security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot erase the element of a map while iterating this way. When you erase the iterator, it becomes invalidated, so you need to explicitly increment it before you delete the element.

Try this code instead:

```
 for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end();)
     if (!((*it).first >= 'a' && (*it).first <= 'z'))
         it = m.erase(it);
     else
        ++it;
```

Comment: `m.erase(it++)` is incorrect. Correct would be `it = m.erase(it)`

Comment: should be `it = m.erase(it);` (to slow by 4 seconds :))

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am still in pre-C++11.

Answer (score 5):

One of the c++ traps is that iterators are invalidated for most containers when they are modified.

[std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::erase - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase)

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other iterators and references are not invalidated.

So when you have remove item form `m` current iterators are become invalid.

Now [range base for loop uses iterators underneath](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

The beast way to fix it us use [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if) algorithm:

```cpp
std::erase_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& i) { 
    return !(std::islower(i.first)); 
});
```